# An error comes up when trying to enter play mode

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hay folks, i pray for everyone's wellbeing. I want to ask a question that whenever i enter playmode in unity, error message is displayed even though there is nothing in the console. This doesn't get fixed even after restarting unity. Any help would be great.[image]

Comment: As the message says, you have to fix all compile errors in your scripts before you can play your game.

Comment: I think you should look at the console. If there was any error, it should appear in the console.

Comment: Disable clear on play.

Comment: Compiler errors wouldn't get cleared btw ;)

Comment: I have done that but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unity, there **can** be compiling errors without any console errors. To fix this the issue is **most definitely** in your code. So go over your code and check that statements return *if* needed. There can always be issues in the IDE (Visual Studio or whatever you are using to write the code) that do not show up in the editor (Unity) due to them being separate programs.